# Some errors in controller (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting some errors in my controller.
At first, I got Suppliers List, then I got Id for all Suppliers, then I got all Users for every Supplier.

```
public ActionResult Grid(bool? active)
    {
        var suppliers = Context.Suppliers.AsNoTracking()
            .WhereIf(active != null, e => e.Active == active)
            .Select(e => new SupplierRow
                            {
                                Id = e.Id,
                                FullName = e.FullName,
                                Active = e.Active,
                                Visits = e.Visits,

                            })
                            .ToList();


        List<int> supplierIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (SupplierRow sr in suppliers)
        {
            supplierIds.Add(sr.Id);
        }

        var users = Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(e => supplierIds.Contains(e.SupplierId))
            .Select(e => new UserRow
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                FullName = e.FullName,
                Email = e.Email,
                Name = e.Name,
                Status = e.Status,
                Role = e.Role,
                SupplierId = e.SupplierId
            }).toList();

        foreach (UserRow ur in users) 
        {
            foreach (SupplierRow sr in supplier) 
            {
                if (ur.SupplierId == sr.Id) 
                {
                    sr.Users.Add(ur);
                } 
            }
        }

        return PartialView("_Grid", suppliers);
    }
```

here
[image]

and here [image]
What's wrong with my code? How to fix that?

Comment: To improve performance and scalability, you should try to combine the two queries into one that is joining the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add `Guid` object to a collection that only accepts `int` values. Your `User.SupplierId` is an object of type `Guid?` (or `Nullable<Guid>`), while `Supplier.Id` is `Guid`. Fix the collection by declaring it as:

```
List<Guid> supplierIds = new List<Guid>();
```

Then in you code use:

```
foreach(SupplierRow sr in suppliers)
{
    supplierIds.Add(sr.Id);
}
```

Do the same thing for users except that you will have to use `SupplierId.HasValue` and `SupplierId.Value` to check whether it has a value and to read the value. This is because it is declared as nullable Guid.

Comment: Yes, I already have found the first error, but I dont understand what should I do with the second error?

Comment: The second error should fix itself if you change the declaration from `List<int>` to `List<Guid>` for supplierIds variable. The error message is telling you that method `Contains` expects int value.

Comment: I changed the declaration `List<Guid> supplierIds = new List<Guid>();` but I continue to get the second error in `.Where(e => supplierIds.Contains(e.SupplierId))` - `some invalid arguments`

Comment: Try `.Where(e => supplierIds.Contains(e.SupplierId.Value))` e.SupplierId is Nullable<Guid> and .Value will return non-Nullable value.

Comment: I tried but no I am getting error here `var users = Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(e => supplierIds.Contains(e.SupplierId.Value))
                .Select(e => new UserRow
                {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    FullName = e.FullName,
                    Email = e.Email,
                    Name = e.Name,
                    Status = e.Status,
                    Role = e.Role,
                    SupplierId = e.SupplierId.Value
                }).toList();` with toList()

Comment: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels.UserRow>' does not contain a definition for 'toList' and no extension method 'toList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels.UserRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It should be .ToList (with capital T)